# Foreach Loop key-value as a Parameter in class object call

Tags: php

I have a PDO query result (array) foreach loop will make a couple of HTML element that contains
the value getting from each row depending on the rows count [ `rows = elements` ].

So basically is when trying to call a class object named `getBusinessName` with a `key-value` as a parameter the method is not giving any output I tried also to pass a defined variable holding the `key-value` and the same condition there is no errors just a blank space no response from the call.

`$db->getBusinessName`

```
    public function getBusinessName($sql,  $params = array()){
        if($this->connected === true){
            try{
                
                $q = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute($params);
                return $q->fetchColumn();
                
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                if($this->errors === true){
                    return $this->error($e->getMessage());
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```
Code:-
```

```
<HTML>
<body>
 <?php $AcBilling = $db->getRows('SELECT * FROM `bills` WHERE statues=true ORDER BY billingdate DESC')?>
            <div class="container-fluid bg-light">
                <?foreach($AcBilling as $activebill){
                    $id = $activebill['pharmacyid'];?> // The key-value //
                    <!-- invoice template -->
                    <div id="<?=$activebill['invoicecodenum']?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header" style="font-family:hana;" role="tab" id="section1HeaderId" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#<?=$activebill['invoicecodenum']?>" href="#section1Content<?=$activebill['invoicecodenum']?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="section1ContentId">
                                <span class="float-left"> <strong>الحالة:</strong> <span style="color:orange;">معلقة</span></span>
                                <h5 class="float-right">طلبية <span id="date" style="font-family:Tahoma !important;">: 12\2\2020</span></h5>
          // The function //     <center><?$db->getBusinessName("SELECT companyarabname FROM accounts WHERE ID='.$id.'"); ?></center> 
                            </div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: you might need to `echo` your `$db->getBusinessName()` call?

Comment: @mikerojas no there is no need for echo because the call will return a string value from the `pharmacyid` column.

Comment: Right but how is that value getting displayed. Like you said it return a string value but when you call it you are not echoing the returned value. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @mikerojas  Yes, you are missing to ensure that I'm not wrong I called the method with an integer `1` instead of `$id` and it works, also tried to define the call in a variable and used (var_dump) and the output is `bool(false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so updating to this below does not work?

```
<center><?php echo $db->getBusinessName("SELECT companyarabname FROM accounts WHERE ID='.$id.'"); ?></center>
```

OR

```
<center><?= $db->getBusinessName("SELECT companyarabname FROM accounts WHERE ID='.$id.'"); ?></center>
```

Comment: Thank you So Much The Seconde Works